# Does WinAPI::InternetCheckConnection put a load on the server?

Tags: winapi, wininet

Our program calls InternetCheckConnection every 2 seconds to test whether the program is connected to our server.

We have around 4000 clients running our program.
Now the server response is slow, despite its processor is almost idle and the free memory is high enough.
Is it possible that InternetCheckConnection puts a load on our server slowing it down?

I also would be happy to know the details of InternetCheckConnection implementation.
MSDN does not tell much.

Comment: Perhaps you should try using a program like wireshark to see what exactly it is doing to check the connection. I agree that MSDN doesn't document this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I have eventually found the answer on another MSDN page.

InternetCheckConnection pings the server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383996%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Great! That is information I was looking for. Ping. 
OK but does anyone knows what timeout is set in `InternetCheckConnection` implementation? It's important for me to know how long (in worst case) I have to wait for executing `InternetCheckConnection`.